# "qfarm > C:\servers.txt" - but I need only the server names

Tags: powershell, citrix

Anyone got any idea how to get the same output file as

```
Get-XAServer | Select -Expand ServerName | Set-Content C:\Servers.txt
```

but with a `qfarm` command? I want only my server names in the txt file. If I do `qfarm > servers.txt` I get the servernames but with IPs and everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`qfarm` is an external program, not a PowerShell cmdlet, so you'll have to parse the information you want out of its text output. Something like this might work:

```
& qfarm /online |
  Select-Object -Skip 3 |
  ForEach-Object { ($_ -split '\s+')[0] } |
  Out-File 'C:\servers.txt'
```

The `Select-Object` statement skips the first 3 lines with the header. The `ForEach-Object` statement then splits each remaining line at whitespace and picks the first field of the resulting array.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `qfarm` you can use it's PowerShell equivalent, the `Get-XAServerLoad` cmdlet:

```
Get-XAServerLoad | Select -Expand ServerName | Set-Content C:\Servers.txt
```